# Hibernate: Date property inside object not saving to database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have a schedule class which contains a list of ScheduleDateActiveItem which has a "date" property.I am setting the list in the Schedule object and saving the schedule Object, saving the object using crudrepository but the "date" property inside ScheduleDateActiveItem is null when I retrieve the saved object.
Using debugging I have confirmed that the object I am trying to save contains the date property,so something is going wrong as I save it.Looking at the database an entry is created for DateActiveScheduleItem with an Id,but the date and schedule_id are null

```
 @Entity
 public class Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id")
private UserGroup userGroup;

private String description;


private boolean master;//is this a schedule for all supervalus(true) or one supervalu(false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<MusicScheduleItem> musicScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<AdvertisementScheduleItem> advertisementScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date dateAdded;
//getters setters}
```

DateActiveScheduleItem

```
@Entity
public class DateActiveScheduleItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date date;



@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
private Schedule schedule;
//getters etters}
```

Comment: Cab you check if there is your 'date' in database?

Comment: Looking at the database an entry is created for DateActiveScheduleItem with an Id,but the date and schedule_id are null

Comment: Entry is created but there are null in database, right?

Comment: Yes it is created  with a valid ID,but date and schedule_id are null in the database entry

Comment: where is your persistence code (the code where you call `persist`)? what does the JPA providers log say about SQL being invoked? aka "debugging"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cascade type to CascadeType.MERGE on dateActiveScheduleItems in schedule fixed it.